# Pygame action when no joystick event

Tags: python, loops, pygame

So i'm building an application that controls a mini drone and to control the drone i use DragonRise Inc. PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad USB joystick in Pygame. What i want it to do, is go through a while loop every 70ms and check if there is a Pygame joystick event. If so than execute some code. If not, then execute some other piece of code.

What I've read online is that is done by checking if the length of the pygame.event.get() list is greater than 0. If so, there is motion, if not (else) no motion. But unfortunately this doesn't work well.

The situation is when i push the joystick axis up, it executes not only the block of code associated with pygame.JOYAXISMOTION event but also the else block of code.

Anyone know how to fix this, or have a better solution ?

```
import time
import pygame

done = False
deadzone = 0.1

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()
joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
joystick.init()

while not done:
    events = pygame.event.get()

    if len(events) > 0:
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
                if joystick.get_axis(1) < -1 * deadzone:
                    print('Throttle Up')
                if joystick.get_axis(1) > deadzone:
                    print('Throttle Down')
    else:
        print('No Event')

    time.sleep(0.07)
```

Comment: it can't execute the `if` and the `else` in the same iteration... Are you sure the indentation in your code matches the indentation here?  PS.  having a 'sleep' in your main loop isn't a great idea. you should implement some sort of timer.

Comment: I copied it directly from Pycharm. Same indentation.

About the if and else part. There lies the problem. When there is no joystick motion it only executes the else part. But when moving the joystick it does both. Mainly the if part, but quite a few times the else part as well

Comment: It is not doing both IF and Else at the same time, that's just not possible. But you might be seeing 'bounce' on the joystick signal as you activate/release.  I.e. it alternates between 'active' and 'inactive' as you start to open or close the switch.  Search for 'debouncing'.  Also you really really don't want to use 'time.sleep()' in a pygame... if nothing else you're limiting your entire game to 14fps!

Comment: It's not going to be used for a game but rather to control a mini drone. The transmitter demands a 70ms update using a binary string. 

The joystick has two 'modes'. Analogue and digital mode. In analogue mode the range is anywhere between -1 and 1. In digital mode it's only -1 or 1. Currently it is in digital mode. 

If i push the stick full up and leave it there, i get the following output:
Throttle Up
Throttle Up
No Event
Throttle Up
etc

Iow there should be an event. Namely joystick up. But somehow the event list is sometimes zero (so else part triggered)

Comment: I think that's probably an electrical question not a software one.  You can send something every 70ms without using 'time.sleep()' .  i.e. keep track of the last time you sent something, and transmit whenever now-last_send >= 70ms.  This way your while loop runs in real time.  May not be an issue now but if you want it to do other things, the sleep will be a problem.

Comment: Try a test script that just gets events and prints `joystick.get_axis(1)` infinitely see what the raw readings actually look like

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to evaluate the `JOYAXISMOTION` at all. [`pygame.joystick.Joystick.get_axis`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html) gets the current position of an axis. Just evaluate the position with a 70ms interval. Use [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) instead of `time.sleep`:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while not done:

    clock.tick(70)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    axis_pos = joystick.get_axis(1)
    if axis_pos < -1 * deadzone:
        print('Throttle Up')
    elif axis_pos > deadzone:
        print('Throttle Down')
    else:
        print('No Event')
```